# How to populate UICollectionViewCells inside of UitableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a uicollectionview cell embedded inside a uitableviewcell. The datasource and delegate of the uicollectionview is connected to the TableviewController. I cant seem to figure how to populate the collectionviews in each tableview cell. Here is the code inside my TableviewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];




    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"item" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 13;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table view cells will need to be the data sources of the collection views they hold. Simply pass the necessary data to the table view cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` method and have the cells populate their respective collection views.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought of but how do I do that? Where would I implement the `cellForItemIndexPath` for the collectionview since thats what populates it.

Comment: That would be implemented inside of your `UITableViewCell` subclass. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had done before.

`collectionView` is an IBOutlet I dragged on to interface builder of the custom table view cell xib.

Inside your custom table view cell class

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //configure collection view
        collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView.scrollEnabled = false
        collectionView.pagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        //....
    }
```

And then implement your delegate and datasource methods

PS: Sorry it's written in Swift but you can convert to Obj-C easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing your collection view's data source and delegate methods in your view controller instead of your table view cell. For example, assuming that this is your table view cell's class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

}
```

You can create a method inside your table view cell's class to set the collection view's data source and delegate methods. Something like:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate <D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>
    (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.tag = row
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Then, inside your `UIViewController` class you can do this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? TableViewCell else { return }

    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
}
```

and your `UIViewController` can conform to the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocols:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10 // 10 here is just an example.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", 
        forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Ash Furrow wrote [a nice blog post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) about UICollectionViews inside UITableView cells, maybe it can be helpful for you.